# What SMD component is this?

Tags: identification, components, plc

Can anyone please help me to find what SMD component this is?

It is connected to 24 VDC on one side side (positive) and the other side to negative.

[image: DFM 1K JEG]

Comment: Possibly a TVS diode used as a spike quencher.

Comment: The logo is Littelfuse so it's probably a TVS. Maybe you can measure the dimensions.

Answer (score 6):

Marking `DFM` could be a SMLJ33CA (Micro commercial components corp) from a google search.

Looking up SMLJ33CA at [www.littelfuse.com](http://www.littelfuse.com) under Competitor Cross Reference, several candidates are shown.  Looking through them, of course the last one shows [a match](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=008d7f63-5963-465a-b796-f69293188900&filename=littelfuse-tvs-diode-smdj-hr-datasheet).  Marking `DFM` is Littelfuse model [SMDJ33CA-HR](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/tvs-diodes/avionics-and-high-reliability/smdj-hr).

This is a 33 Volt TVS or Transient Voltage Suppressor.  These are like Zener diodes, in that once a certain threshold voltage is reached, they start to conduct.  The net effect is that they clamp a voltage surge and prevent it from getting much higher.

These are commonly used on the power inputs of devices to prevent damage from over-voltage stress.

Comment: Good answer and good research

Comment: Thank you rdtsc